# Convert cv2 shape from python to c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have below lines of code which is in `python`. I need to convert it into its equivalent `c++`..

```
lowH = 0
lowS = 150
lowV = 42

highH = 11
highS = 255
highV = 255

crop = 15
height = 40
perc = 23

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

threshold_img = cv2.inRange(hsv, (lowH, lowS, lowV), (highH, highS, highV))

x = 0
y = int(threshold_img.shape[0] * crop / 100)
w = int(threshold_img.shape[1])
h = int(threshold_img.shape[0] * height / 100)
img_cropped = threshold_img[y: y + h, x: x + w]

if cv2.countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.size * perc / 100:
    print("False")
else:
    print("True")
```

For above code, I have converted this in `c++` which looks like below:

```
int lowH = 0;
int lowS = 150;
int lowV = 42;

int highH = 11;
int highS = 255;
int highV = 255;

int crop = 15;
int height = 40;
int perc = 23;

cv::Mat hsv, threshold_img, img_cropped;

cv::cvtColor(img, hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

cv::inRange(hsv, cv::Scalar(lowH, lowS, lowV), cv::Scalar(highH, highS, highV), threshold_img);

int x = 0;
int y = int(threshold_img.reshape[0] * crop / 100);   <- error
int w = int(threshold_img.reshape[1]);                <- error
int h = int(threshold_img.reshape[0] * height / 100); <- error
img_cropped = threshold_img.resize[y + h, x + w];     <- error

if (cv::countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.size * perc / 100)
{
    cout << "False" << endl;
}

else
    cout << "TRUE" << endl;
```

But the above code is giving error

> Error C2109 subscript requires array or pointer type

and also this error

> Error (active)    E0349   no operator "*" matches these operands

at line

```
if (cv::countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.size * perc / 100)
```

In line

```
y = int(threshold_img.shape[0] * crop / 100)
```

there was no `shape` available so I used `reshape`.

Can anyone please guide me on how can I resolve these error and what author in python code is trying to achieve so that I can convert that easily in c++. Please help. Thanks

Comment: img_cropped.size in c++ return opencv::Size object this is why you get the error, I think you can do img_cropped.rows * img_cropped.cols insted of img_cropped.size.

Comment: Thanks but I didnt get you properly. can you answer it in more details

Comment: python            ->     c++
threshold_img.shape[0]  -> threshold_img.rows
 threshold_img.shape[1]  -> threshold_img.cols
img_cropped.size  -> Size() this object that have height and width members see https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Size.html

Comment: Thanks I have resolved few issues. I am not able to get these two lines in python only: `img_cropped = threshold_img[y: y + h, x: x + w]`

`if cv2.countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.size * perc / 100:`

Comment: "cv2.countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.size * perc / 100" countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.rows * img_cropped.cols /100

Comment: Can you please answer this question so that I can also accept it.

Comment: img_cropped = threshold_img[y: y + h, x: x + w]
is to get sub image of threshold_img that start at y to y+h and from x to  x + wimg_cropped = threshold_img(Rect(x,y,w,h))

Comment: @alon What about `perc` in your comment `countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.rows * img_cropped.cols /100`

Comment: sory I forget * perc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python -> c++

```
threshold_img.shape[0] -> threshold_img.rows 
threshold_img.shape[1] -> threshold_img.cols
```

img_cropped.size -> Size() this object that have height and width members see

```
"cv2.countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.size * perc / 100" 
 countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.rows * img_cropped.cols * perc /100
```

img_cropped = threshold_img[y: y + h, x: x + w] is to get sub image of threshold_img that start at y to y+h and from x to x +

```
img_cropped = threshold_img(Rect(x,y,w,h))
```

note place check the x, y, width, height, rows, cals values to see that I wasn't confused the axis